# The import org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache

I'm trying to import this library in order to use the RandomStringUtils class, but always I'm getting the error in the title of the question.

This is an ANT project, so I downloaded the library from Apache (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) and put it in the lib folder of the project. However, it's not working.

I got another library in this folder (org.apache.commons.cli) and it's working fine.

**edit**: ok, this is solved... It's a bug in Eclipse saying the import cannot be resolved.

Comment: Extract *.tar.gz, and put *.jar file in the lib folder.

Comment: @ztelnet that's what I did...

Comment: Did u get the solution ?

Comment: @usergk yes. It's working although Eclipse keeps saying it cannot resolve the import. I guess it's a bug in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is solved... It's a bug in Eclipse saying the import cannot be resolved.

Comment: How did you fixed?